# Why this formula not always works?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This formula

```
-s Sum[f[s x], x] // FullSimplify
Limit[%, s -> 0]
Limit[%, x -> 0]
```

Should give the same as

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

Now if `f[x_]=Sin[x]/x` the result is wrong. Why?

The formula gives correct result, $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ for functions like $\frac1{(x+1)^r}$ for $r>1$, for $\sin ax$ and $\cos ax$ it gives Abel integration result, for $\exp ax$ it gives correct result when converges and analytic continuation when does not.

Comment: Why do you have a minus sign in front of `Sum`?  Without it, I get the same result as from `Integrate`.  What do you get? What version fo Mathematica?

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, I also have the difference in sign, but in all other cases this formula works. If to swap the limits it even gives 0 for this function... Mathematica 11.

Comment: this maybe belongs on math.stackexchange.com, but i guess the issue relates to neglecting the implied constant associated with the indefinite sum.  (Maybe showing an example `f` where it does work for you would be a good idea too )

Comment: @george2079 constant does not matter here, you can add any constant to the sum, it will vanish because multiplied by s, which goes to 0.

Comment: @george2079 it works for 1/(x+1)^2 and higher powers, a^(-x), for sin(ax), cos(ax) it gives Abel integration result, also works for other cases where Abel does not converge.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are using an indefinite sum to compute a definite integral, but you never explicitly use the *limits of the summation/integration* in your question.  The problem is exactly here—in the part you left out.  I think you made assumptions about the value of the function at 0 and infinity, and that's how you ended up with the minus sign. But those assumptions may not always be valid. If you use definite summation, then the results will be correct.